# Facebook Graph Api , access posts in story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a way to access the posts in stories using facebook graph api. So on my birthday 97 people wrote on my timeline which has become a single story(as evident from the 1st object in my feed output below). Is there a way to access the individual posts of that story? Graph api `/me/feed/` returns the below output.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "story": "Mr. X and 96 others wrote on your Timeline.",
      "created_time": "2016-06-28T18:02:04+0000",
      "id": "post id here"
    },
    {
      "message": "Random post",
      "created_time": "2016-06-23T16:04:09+0000",
      "id": "post id here"
    },
    {
      "message": "Shared article",
      "created_time": "2016-06-21T05:24:08+0000",
      "id": "post id here"
    },
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "previous_url_here",
    "next": "next_url_here"
  }
}
```